# Expose WCF digitally signed service via HTTPS

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding

By specs I have to expose service via HTTPS which is digitally signed.

I have configured HTTPS service on IIS and web.config, and that part is working.
I'm using basicHttpBinding 'cos service have to use SOAP 1.1

web.config:

```
    <services>
        <service name="Namespace.MyService"
                 behaviorConfiguration="TestServiceBehaviour">

            <endpoint address="https://url/TestService.svc"
                      binding="basicHttpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="TestServiceBinding"
                      contract="Namespace.IMyService" />
        </service>

    </services>

    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="TestServiceBinding">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="TestServiceBehaviour">
                <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>

        <endpointBehaviors>

        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

But I'm stuck with signing part.

netTcpBinding can use Sign as protectionLevel.
Is it possible to do something like that with basicHttpBinding?